# After adding CNAMEs, the WWW version of domain doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Tags: dns, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Cloudfront as a CDN, and I'm using CNAME entries at my hosting company to show my domain name in lieu of the cloudfront address.

To that end, my DNS entries at the host are formatted like this:

```
cdn.example.com CNAME 14400 123456789.cloudfront.net

www.cdn.example.com CNAME 14400 123456789.cloudfront.net
```

After waiting for them to propagate, I tested both at DNSchecker.org.

The first version (cdn.example.com) points to the CloudFront distribution as I'd hoped.

But, the second version (www.cdn.example.com) doesn't point anywhere.

Any idea why one would point to CloudFront but not the other?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but 1) There is no DNS propagation, this is a myth or a severe and wrong simplification. If you do a change on your authoritative nameservers it should be published immediately and can be checked immediately 2) do not obfuscate names, the DNS is public and you will get better replies with real names and 3) do not obfuscate badly, `domain.com` exists and is certainly not yours and 4) "doesn't point anywhere" is not clear troubleshooting. Use dig or nslookup, show queries you did (towards authoritative nameservers!) and replies you got

Comment: Thank you pointing me in the right direction (in terms of both topic and the issue itself). I'll take both under advisement.